# plot with matplotlib and pandas from cdv file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I know that is general question, but I just start to learn python, so I'm so sorry !!

I have a csv file, that I want to plot it in a stacked bar chart (something like this picture [bar_stacked_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkWVL.png) in the imagen the Control, IAC-data and Mix, are equal to my data set:  S1, S2, S3).

The file has a data like:

```
# any comment
sp     S1    S2   S3
name_1  9    15   18
name_2  3    11   9
name_3  12    5   7
name_4  5     9   10
name_x  15    3   1
```

so

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(my_file.csv, sep='\t', skiprows=1)

data.set_index('sp', inplace=True)

xdata = data.columns.values

plt.ylabel('Y legend')
plt.xlabel('X legend')
plt.title('Scores of any data')

plt.plot(data[xdata])

plt.show()
```

it give me a line plot, and I want a stacked bar, so I want to define the 
x axis as data corresponding to columns : s1    s2   s3
and 
y axis with the values of: name_1 name_2 name_3 name_4 name_x

Answer (score 0):

So you want something like:

```
df.set_index('sp').T.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, figsize=(16,9))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]